# Beracha of Knowledge

Tags: blessing, shemoneh-esrei, parashat-bereishit

We say in the 4th beracha of shemoneh esrei that G-d gave us knowledge and we thank him for this. Yes, obviously everything comes from G-d, but in the beginning of humankind we had no knowledge, and only attained it once Adam ate from the Tree of Knowledge. So Hashem didn’t give us knowledge purposely, it sorta happened by accident and unintentionally. So why do we thank G-d for giving us knowledge if he didn’t really give it to us, but rather we took it?

Comment: was the tree the cause of having all knowledge or just a specific kind? If Adam was able to walk and talk (and name the animals) beforehand, he must have had some sort of knowledge already. The bracha covers different kinds of "knowing".

Comment: @rosends I suppose you’re right. I do wonder how much knowledge Adam had before he ate from the tree and what exactly changed once he did eat from it. The Torah only says that the knowledge was that he realized he was naked, but I wonder if like all complex thought came as a result of the tree or if he had the ability beforehand

Comment: The tree was specifically called the tree of knowing good and evil so it was about a moral sense not knowing general stuff

Comment: In the beginning of _Moreh Nevuchim_, the Rambam talks about the impossibility of having man's greatest attribute come through as a result of a mistake. I very strongly suggest you follow the discussion there.